# Firebase return function after Snapshot function is finished

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want my function to return, after the `((querySnapshot) => {...` function is finished.
At the moment, my `noOpponent` function returns always `false` after calling, Thats probably because its returning, before the `((querySnapshot) => {...` function is finished and so its returned, before the `state` is set `true`. I already tried to call the noOpponent function with `var a = await noOpponent(key)`, but its not working, because as i already wrote, I think i have to await for the `((querySnapshot) => {...` function. How can I do this?

```
export const noOpponent = (Key) => {
  var state = false;
  console.log("key: " + Key)
  duettsRef
    .where("key", "==", Key)
    .where("player1", "!=", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .where("player2", "==", "")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
     console.log("QuerysnapshotResult: " + !querySnapshot.empty);
     state = true;
      })
      return state;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers propose to use `async`/`await`, which is very good and recommended for code readability.

Let's show here how you should do if you still want to use `then()`:

```
export const noOpponent = (Key) => {
  var state = false;
  console.log("key: " + Key)
  return duettsRef    // <=== See the return here. More at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining 
    .where("key", "==", Key)
    .where("player1", "!=", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .where("player2", "==", "")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
       console.log("QuerysnapshotResult: " + !querySnapshot.empty);
       state = true;

       return state;   // See how we call return in the then block and not outside of it

    });
      
};
```

Note that the `noOpponent()` function is asynchronous and returns a Promise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
export const noOpponent = async (Key) => {
  var state = false;
  console.log("key: " + Key)
  let querySnapshot = await duettsRef
    .where("key", "==", Key)
    .where("player1", "!=", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .where("player2", "==", "")
    .limit(1)
    .get();
    
   // do something like assign value to state then return
      return state;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a perfect fit for `async/await`. It turns async code to something like sync code. You would need to write your code like this:

```js
export const noOpponent = async (Key) => {
  var state = false;
  console.log("key: " + Key)
  const querySnapshot = await duettsRef
    .where("key", "==", Key)
    .where("player1", "!=", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .where("player2", "==", "")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    
 console.log("QuerysnapshotResult: " + !querySnapshot.empty);
 state = true;
      
 return state;
};
```

Make sure when you call `noOpponent` to also use async or then.

```js
noOpponent('key').then(state=>{
  console.log('state',state)
})
```